# Disallowed Key Characters. error while loading embed code in frame through jquery in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am loading my embed code in iframe through jQuery like this

```
<div id="My-page" style="width:900px; height:900px; position: absolute;overflow-x:hidden !important;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;" class="iframely-widget-container">
    <script>
        $("#My-page").empty().append($("<iframe/>", {
            src: "http://localhost/flipbeets3.0.com/get-embedded-code/abdul/p~2~2~2?slug-hash=HrFBx&amp;default-tab=result&amp;host=http%3A%2F%2Fcodepen.io"
        }));
    </script>
</div>
```

it is showing disallowed key characters error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to encode the URL when you load it via javascript. This code should work for you:

```
<div id="My-page" style="width:900px; height:900px; position: absolute;overflow-x:hidden !important;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;" class="iframely-widget-container"></div><script>$("#My-page").empty().append($("<iframe/>", {src: "http://localhost/flipbeets3.0.com/get-embedded-code/abdul/p~2~2~2?slug-hash=HrFBx&default-tab=result&host=http://codepen.io"}));</script>
```